# How to move /var back to Root from a different filesystem

Tags: filesystems, partition, root, fstab, var

I need to move my /var (dev/sdc1) back to the / (dev/sda2) from a different file system. I've resized the / partition and want to move /var back to / partition and resize /dev/sdc1 filesystem to mount another directory /data002

Currently,
[df -h and lsblk details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxuwg.png)
Can someone guide me on this please.

Comment: this could help https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88256/how-to-move-to-a-different-drive-or-partition

Comment: Your request is a little unclear - specifically do the contents if /var exist in the new location? I am pretty sure a key part of what you are looking for is describing the mapping of the block device in /etc/fstab - but this may or may not be the full story.

Comment: @davidgo Initially, due to limited space in / partition I moved my /var directory and mounted to /dev/sdc1. Now I have resized the / partition and I need to use /dev/sdc1 for another directory, so I want to move /var directory back to / and unmount it from /dev/sdc1.

Comment: (As you are new to this, back up first) Looking at your link, I suspect you should use a boot disk, mount /dev/sda1 and /dev/sdc1. Copy the contents if /dev/sdc1 to /dev/sda1::/var and then modify /dev/sda1:/etc/fstab and comment out the /var line. Reboot.

Comment: (Also, for future reference, if you land up rebuilding this system, use LVM - LVM abstracts disks from volumes and makes reallocating resources easier)

Comment: @davidgo, Is this the correct way to do it:  mkdir /var_new
mv /var/* /var_new/
umount -fl /var
mv /var_new /var
Remove /var from fstab

Comment: That looks about right. (Not sure about forcing unmounts). Also, I would be inclined to copy rather then move /var (and delete afterwards) - that way if it turns to custard you can revert back.

Comment: @davidgo when I try to umount the /var drive from /dev/sdc1 I get the error stating the resource is busy.

Comment: "lsof -D /var" might tell you what files are open and give you a clue what process needs to be stopped.  Otherwise do it from a USB booted session where nothing is mounted.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest two options :

1- No downtime is tolerated (Use it at your own risk) :

- Issue the following commands :

---

```
mkdir /vartmp
rsync -aqxP /var/* /vartmp
```

- Force umounting of /var by :

---

```
umount -f /var (force umount)
        OR
umount -l /var (lazy umount)
```

- Rename your directories :

---

```
mv /var /varbackup (keep your old /var in case of you encounter an issue)
mv /vartmp /var
```

- Edit */etc/fstab* :

---

```
vi /etc/fstab (Delete the line containing '/dev/sdc1 /var')
```

2- Downtime is tolerated, make sure you have access to the server console directly because network will be down in single user mode and note that */var* will **not be mounted** also :

SYSTEM V based Debian:

- Reboot the server
- Choose you kernel and then press *e* to edit the grub entry.
- Append init=/bin/bash to the end of the grub line which begins with linux.
- Now press ctrl-x or F10 to boot into single user mode.
- Enter the following commands :

---

```
mkdir /vartmp
rsync -aqxP /var/* /vartmp
mv /var /varbackup (keep your old /var in case of you encounter an issue)
mv /vartmp /var
vi /etc/fstab (Delete the line containing '/dev/sdc1 /var')
reboot
```

SYSTEMD based Debian :

```
systemctl set-default rescue.target
reboot 
mkdir /vartmp
rsync -aqxP /var/* /vartmp
mv /var /varbackup (keep your old /var in case of you encounter an issue)
mv /vartmp /var
vi /etc/fstab (Delete the line containing '/dev/sdc1 /var')
systemctl set-default <graphical.target (OR) multi-user.target>
reboot
```

P.S : Try to use LVMs in future they are flexible and can deal more efficiently with this kind of situation using just **vgsplit** & **pvmove** OR using **lvm mirroring** & **lvm mirror discarding**